# Replace " with \"

Tags: scala

How do I replace " with \".

Here is what im trying :

```
def main(args:Array[String]) = {      
  val line:String = "replace \" quote";
  println(line);
  val updatedLine = line.replaceAll("\"" , "\\\"");
  println(updatedLine);
}
```

output :

```
replace " quote
replace " quote
```

The output should be :

```
replace " quote
replace \" quote
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two more `\\` does the job:

```
scala>  line.replaceAll("\"" , "\\\\\"");
res5: java.lang.String = replace \" quote
```

The problem here is that there are two 'layers' escaping the strings. The first layer is the compiler, which we can easily see in the REPL:

```
scala> "\""
res0: java.lang.String = "

scala> "\\"
res1: java.lang.String = \

scala> "\\\""
res2: java.lang.String = \"

scala> val line:String = "replace \" quote";
line: String = replace " quote
```

The second layer is the regular expression interpreter. This one is harder to see, but can be seen by applyin your example:

```
scala>  line.replaceAll("\"" , "\\\"");
res5: java.lang.String = replace " quote
```

What the reg. exp. interpreter really receives is \", which is interpreted as only ". So, we need the reg. exp. to receive \\". To make the compiler give us \ we need to write \\.

Let's see the unescaping:

- The right case: \\\" the compiler sees \", the regular expression sees \".
- The wrong case: \\" the compiler sees \", the regular expression sees ".

It can be a bit confusing despite being very straight forward.

As pointed by @sschaef, another alternative it to use """ triple-quoting, strings in this form aren't unescaped by the compiler:

```
scala>  line.replaceAll("\"" , """\\"""");
res6: java.lang.String = replace \" quote
```

Comment: val updatedLine = line.replaceAll("\"" , "\\\\\"") worked for me (I needed 5 quotes for some reason).

Comment: To avoid confusion, I suggest using `"""..."""` instead of `"..."`

Comment: @sschaef, well said. It was going to be in the answer but I completely forgot about it as soon as I realized it would be more useful to explain what is really going on.

Answer (score 14):

Use "replaceAllLiterally" method of StringOps class. This replaces all literal occurrences of the argument:

```
scala> val line:String = "replace \" quote"
line: String = replace " quote

scala> line.replaceAllLiterally("\"", "\\\"")
res8: String = replace \" quote
```

Comment: And what is the difference between .replaceAllLiterally and .replace?

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this one!

Answer (score 0):

@pedrofurla nicely explains why you saw the behavior you did. Another solution to your problem would be to use a raw string with scala's triple-quote character. Anything between a pair of triple-quotes is treated as a raw string with no interpretation by the Scala compiler. Thus:

```
scala> line.replaceAll("\"", """\\"""")
res1: String = replace \" quote
```

Used in conjunction with `stripMargin`, triple-quotes are a powerful way to embed raw strings into your code. For example:

```
val foo = """
        |hocus
        |pocus""".stripMargin
```

yields the string: `"\nhocus\npocus"`