# Is there ever a reason to use Scala's StringLike.replaceAllLiterally over Java's String.replace?

Tags: java, scala

Scala's StringLike has the method [`replaceAllLiterally(literal: String, replacement: String): String`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/56b7c0f8fa6c1037905867aec88520476dbd3baa/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/StringLike.scala#L166)

This seems to be very similar in effect to Java's String with the method [`String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Is there ever a reason to use the Scala version?

(Not going through the regex compile step would seem to enable Java's version to be faster, though I haven't benchmarked that)

Comment: Yes. The reason -- you are hating to escape characters.

Comment: Just looked up the java source - turns out for the CharSequence version (as opposed to the single-char-version), Java also just compiles literal regexes. Seems like there's no real difference between them other than the name and the StringBuilder overload mentioned by @RexKerr.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: I was referencing String.replace, not String.replaceAll (where you'd need to do the escaping you mention).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's to avoid collision with `replace` on `StringBuilder`.  `StringBuilder` is also a `StringLike`.  Why the `StringBuilder` `replace` wasn't the one to be changed, I'm not sure.

There's no reason to use it on strings unless you want to handle any `StringLike` (i.e. both wrapped strings and their builders).

Comment: Since Scala 2.12 or 2.13 (I am not sure exactly when), the compiler issues a deprecation warning when using `replaceAllLiterally` on a `String` and recommends using `replace` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is very helpful to use Scala's method to avoid the confusion of being buried by escape characters. Stack Overflow users [@pedrofurla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/480674/pedrofurla) and [@rampart81](https://stackoverflow.com/users/763002/rampart81) explain it all quite well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115187/replace-with).

Comment: Java's `String.replaceAll` uses regexes and escape characters, but `String.replace` does not.  I'm not sure that's the right comparison.

Comment: Scala has all the Java `replace*` methods too in `StringOps` via implicit conversion. I figured the OP was asking what makes the uniquely Scala method `replaceAllLiterally` useful or even preferable.