# Replacing string containing parenthesis

Tags: regex, scala

In this string:

```
val s = "pow(10,3) + pow(10,3) + pow(10,3)"
```

I need to replace

```
pow(10,3)
```

with

```
1000
```

So the end result would be

```
1000 + 1000 + 1000
```

I tried with

```
s.replaceAll("pow(10,3)", "1000")
```

However this doesn't work as the first argument is a regex, and the parenthesis represent a group. The statement above actually doesn't replace anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Use : pow\\(10,3\\)  because parenthesis is the for group

Comment: Tried `s.replace("pow(10,3)", "1000")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew isn't string replace work with characters only?

Comment: `replace` replaces literal strings. **See [this Scala demo](https://ideone.com/Hnsuop)**. `replaceAll` uses a regex pattern to search for strings to replace. What do you actually need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replace a literal string, do not use `replaceAll`, use `replace`.

See [this Scala demo](https://ideone.com/Hnsuop):

```
val s = "pow(10,3) + pow(10,3) + pow(10,3)";
print(s.replace("pow(10,3)", "1000"));
// => 1000 + 1000 + 1000
```

If you need to use `replaceAll`, the literal parentheses must be escaped with a doubled backslash:

```
s.replaceAll("pow\\(10,3\\)", "1000")
```

Or, use a triple-quoted string literal and use a single backslash to escape the special regex metacharacters:

```
s.replaceAll("""pow\(10,3\)""", "1000")
```

See [this Scala demo](https://ideone.com/zCcl2F) and [another one here](https://ideone.com/qz42xk).

**Both `replaceAll` and `replace` will replace *multiple* occurrences**.

Beside the `replace`, you may use [`replaceAllLiterally(literal: String, replacement: String): String`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/56b7c0f8fa6c1037905867aec88520476dbd3baa/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/StringLike.scala#L166)

See also [**Is there ever a reason to use Scala's StringLike.replaceAllLiterally over Java's String.replace?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665369/is-there-ever-a-reason-to-use-scalas-stringlike-replaceallliterally-over-javas)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I don't get why you need to double backslash the parenthesis, it's a Scala thing?

Comment: Ok, you do not *always* have to. If you use triple-quoted string literal, you may use a single backslash - [`s.replaceAll("""pow\(10,3\)""", "1000")`](https://ideone.com/qz42xk). The point is that the double quoted string literals can have escape sequences like `\n`, so the backslash is written as `"\\"`, and we need a *literal* backslash to escape regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `(` and `)` with `\` else it's treated as group

```js
var re = /pow\(10,3\)/g; 
var str = 'pow(10,3) + pow(10,3) + pow(10,3)';
var subst = '1000'; 
 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
console.log(result);
```

Update :  for scala

you need to double escape the bracket as :`str.replaceAll("pow\\(10,3\\)", "1000"))`

Comment: I need to do this with scala, not javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try `replaceAllLiterally`, it accepts `String literal` as input.

```
val str = "pow(10,3) + pow(10,3) + pow(10,3)";
println(str.replaceAllLiterally("pow(10,3)", "1000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the parenthesis with backslashes so they are treated like another character:

```
"""pow\(10,3\)"""
```

Comment: is this scala or javascript?

Comment: It's a regex expression, in your code it would look like: `s.replaceAll("pow\(10,3\)", "1000")`

Comment: How do I convert the string `pow(10,3)` to `pow\(10,3\)` in scala?

Comment: I don't quite get your question, just change the string inside your replaceAll for the one with the backslashes

Comment: I don't know how to change it, because it has parenthesis. It's a variable in the code.

Comment: And you can't change it on the definition of the variable? Can you provide part of the actual code you're trying to implement this in?